# Plot ROC curve using tensorflow model with multiclass

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, roc

I have trained a CNN model using tensorflow to classify 5 classes.

How do I plot the ROC curve for each of 5 classes with one-versus-rest?

From the scikit page, it says:

```
for i in range(n_classes):
    fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])
    roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
```

But tensorflow dataset, I don't have this "y_test" and "y_score" dataset structure
And every other tutorial website just copies the same code

I use "tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory" to generate a test_ds variable

How do I get the tpr and fpr with model.predict function on test_ds? or other methods?

How do I get this "y_test" and "y_score" from model.predict and test_ds?

Apart from one-versus-rest, how could I plot the ROC for specific class 1 versus class 3?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the meaning of "y_score[:, i]"?

Comment: Can you post an example of your predicted probabilities ('y_socre`) and observed labels (`y_test`)? Perhaps we can turn the tensors to numpy arrays or work with tensors directly.